# Linux 3.8: omap serial driver : write data sliced in two = why?

Tags: serial-port, embedded-linux, omap

I've a problem with my Program, I'm trying to send 14 bytes of data (one single call of write), but the data got sliced in two packet .... which make the other device respond with an crc error ..... why ? why the driver linux decide to cut my data ? do you know any configuration of the serial port that can prevent that ? or other solution ?

thank you very much !

!blue= rts , red = rs485 data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8beT.jpg

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: you might be seeing an interaction with the UART buffer size.

Comment: I finally found out the problem ... I had a memory leak ..... + The Kernel is compiled with the preempt mode. So, while the driver tried to send the data, The Kernel interrupted temporary the transmission to do something with the memory ( purge ? ). Since I fixed the memory leak, I don't have any problem now ...